Testing a react component library project using vite
I have a library project using TS, React, and vite for bundler. Folder structure looks like this
- LibraryProject
 - src
  - main
   - TestComponent.tsx
  - hooks
   - hookFile.ts
  - enums
   - enumFile.enum.ts

My current vite config builds a lib properly and I am able to use that in a separate React demo project.
To import my Library project into the react demo project, I am using the default npm install command followed by the ../pathToLibraryProject. Once the project is linked I am able to reference the main file but unable to import enums or hooks.
Current import statement,
import TestComponent, { enumA } from "library-project";

TestComponent as I mentioned is imported correctly but not ENUM_A.
Error,
ERROR in ./src/App.js 46:22-39
export 'enumA' (imported as 'enumA') was not found in 'library-project' (possible exports: default)

Can anyone point out what can possibly fix this?
Thanks.

EDIT: I tried the following as per the comments but it seems there is something I am missing as I still get error on resolving the imports in the demo project. Code below,
"exports": {
    ".": {
      "import": "./dist/index.es.js",
      "require": "./dist/index.cjs.js"
    },
    "./src/enums/enumFile.enum.ts": "./src/enums/index.ts"
  },

This still results in the following error in the demo project,
Attempted import error: 'enumA' is not exported from 'library-project' (imported as 'enumA').
ERROR in ./src/App.js 46:22-39
export 'enumA' (imported as 'enumA') was not found in 'library-project' (possible exports: default)

webpack compiled with 1 error


You need to define the entry (or entries) to your package. As example, define exports: { ".": "./src/index.ts" } in your package.json, then create a src/index.ts file. In you index, you can write things like export { default as TestComponent } from "./main/TestComponent" and export { enumA, enumB } from "./enums/enumFile.ts" etc

Thank you. let me give this a try as well. For now I only have a single entry. I was expecting that my tsconfig already have includes all src folder files on it so it should pick up the enum files automatically on its own. Do I need to separately provide an entry point for that as well? I am already exporting all my enums, hooks and the main file component

@Mulan -  Just tried it but unfortunately that did not work because ".":"./src/index.ts"  comppiles the library project with errors. Getting Module not found: Error: Can't resolve on every file listed in the index.ts

The TypeScript compiler is separate from the package resolver. When a package package is imported using import, see exports and main. Each file/module defines its own exports. Your package entry (or entries) defines what the package exports.

@Mulan: I have edited my question with what you suggested. Kindly see and please let me know what am I doing wrong. I did read the links above and followed an example best suited. thank you

According to your edit, your package is exporting dist.es.js file. Does that file exist? Is it exporting enumA?

If you write "./src/enums/enumFile.enum.ts": "./src/enums/index.ts" in your exports field, that means you to write import { foo } from "library-package/src/enums/enumFile.enum.ts" to resolve the src/enums/index.ts file. I don't think that's what you want. Read my first comment more carefully. You should understand single entry point "." before attempting multiple package entries

Yep it worked. Thank you! I had to also change the entry in vite config

I followed @Mulans instructions in the comments yesterday. The only thing extra I had to do was change the entry in vite.config.ts.
Here are the changes that worked for me,
Vite Config:
entry: "./src/index.tsx",

Kept my exports as following,
"exports": {
    ".": {
      "import": "./dist/index.es.js",
      "require": "./dist/index.cjs.js"
    }
  },

Since I need to support CommonJS and ES versions. Thank you for all the help
